# PHP display first and last name of logged in user

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I want to display the name of the logged in user, but since there is no field to input name when logging in, the session only gets the email and password values. How can I display name?

my `server.php`

```
<?php
include_once "inc/user-connection.php";

session_start();

$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['name']);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['password']);
$hashed_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['email']);
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['username']);

if (isset($_POST['admin-sign-in'])) {
    if (!empty($email)) {
        if (!empty($password)) {
           
            $sql = 'SELECT email, password FROM admin WHERE email = ?';

            // preparing the SQL statement
            if ($stmt = $conn->prepare($sql)) {
                $stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['email']);
                $stmt->execute();
                $stmt->store_result(); // Store the result so we can check if the account exists in the database.

                // If email exists in sign_up table
                if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
                    $stmt->bind_result($email, $password);
                    $stmt->fetch();

                    // if password user enters matches the one in the database
                    if (password_verify($password, $hashed_password)) {
                        $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
                        $_SESSION['name'] = $row['name'];

                        // upon successful login, redirect user to landing apge
                        header("location: dashboard.php");
                        die();
                    } else {
                        // Incorrect password
                        header("location: ../html/sign-in-error.html");
                        die();
                    }
                } else {
                    // Incorrect username
                    header("location: ../html/sign-in-error.html");
                    die();
                }
                $stmt->close();
            }
        } else {
            header("location: ../html/404-error.html");
            die();
        }
    } else {
        header("location: ../html/404-error.html");
        die();
    }
}
```

my `dashboard.php`

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<div class="d-block">
<h1 class="lead fw-normal text-muted mb-4 px-lg-10">Hello, <?php echo $_SESSION['name']; ?></h1>
</div>
```

sign-in page
[image]

Dashboard: should display first and last name but is empty(It can display email, but I don't want that)
[image]

The `$name` variable contains both first and last name, there is only one column for name in the table.

Comment: The logic in your code doesn't really make sense. First you select all fields from admin which has the posted email (which also is wide open for SQL injection). If you then fetch the values you got from the database (always assuming you actually found something). If the email and password is not empty, you fetch the user data _again_? This time only selecting email and password from the database? This makes no sense.

Comment: You should also _never_ store passwords in plain text! You should only store password hashes generated using [password_hash()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and to verify a password againts a hash, use [password_verify()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php).

Comment: Regarding your actual question, just fetch the name in your select and add that as a session variable as well, as you're doing with the email.

Comment: You shouldn't manually escape data using `mysqli_real_escape_string()`. Use prepared statements everywhere instead (which you for some reason are doing for only one request, but not for the others)

Comment: per the suggestions: I added the prepared statement for sign-up used `password_hash()` and `password_verify()` when checking password. Did I do it right?? Also Can someone help with the actual answer?

Answer (score 1):

Like commented on your question, when doing the sign in, just fetch the names from the database when you check user login details and to ease your pain you can store these names to your `$_SESSION` so you can call it whenever you need it if the session is up.

`$_SESSION['first_name'] = $name;`

Should not be harder than that. Only thing confusing was that you store your sign ups to different table than you use in sign in, but there seems to be admin and user tables seperately.

Offtopic: You could just add column to your users table for like `admin` with `BOOLEAN` or `rank` with actual rank name